# Open source PHP reporting tool

Tags: php, reporting

I am developing web based application, i need php reporting lib/class to make the job easy.
I need PDF/Excel format. The report based on related db tables(member bills, member info) Is there any advanced open source solution ?

Thanks

Comment: @Fellow_StackOverflow, Please do not close questions related to software tools. Refer 3rd point in http://stackoverflow.com/faq!

Answer (score 5):

There are tons of reporting libraries, most of which create Xml or Csv.  You would have to give more data about what kind of reporting you need for a recommendation.  I haven't used [PHPExcel](http://openxmldeveloper.org/articles/4606.aspx) yet, but it is the first attempt I have seen to actually create Excel documents rather than creating CSV's that will load in Excel.  PDF creation is built into PHP with the [PDF functions](http://www.php.net/pdf), and is fairly easy to do.

**[UPDATE]**

PHPExcel is archived now you can use [PhpSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet) instead.

Comment: PHPExcel is a great library which works as advertised.
It does require php5.2.x with mbstrings, xmlwriter and zip extensions installed. 
It can read and output excel 97(xls) and excel 2007 files(xlsx).
It can even use excels formulas to calculate a value.

Comment: PHPExcel is DEAD - https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/README.md

Answer (score 5):

A newer library that looks very promising is [PHP Reports by jdorn on github](http://jdorn.github.io/php-reports/).

This is unrelated to [the older library by the same name hosted on Sourceforge](http://phpreports.sourceforge.net/).

[image: basic report image]

Comment: This is nice library to use for mySQL reporting.

Comment: @lolcode, I have been trying to get this up and running with my AppGini Application but i have hit a deadend. Would you please help me out. Av been using this [AppGini Community Forum](http://forums.appgini.com/phpbb/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=1797) and [Php Reports](http://jdorn.github.io/php-reports/) . The issue is getting the reports / list of reports to display on my Application.

Answer (score 3):

A bit late, but you might want to check out RLib - works with PHP and MySQL and creates multiple different types - PDF, CSV, HTML etc.

http://rlib.sicompos.com/

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't know of a decent reporting class in PHP.

Do you need a full reporting suite, or do you just need to be able to export data to the pdf and Excel file formats?

If you only need to create these kind of pages, the simplest solution would be to display the data you require and add CutePdf software which installs itself as a printer. Then you can print to pdf from the browser.

If you need to create pdf files on the server side, there is a pdf creation library in the Zend Framework. ZendFramework-1.8.1\library\Zend\Pdf

Answer (score 0):

I recommend giving this PHP reporting library a try:

https://github.com/webuccinoco/sre-community

You can also download it via the following composer command:

composer create-project webuccinoco/sre-community