# Good practice for generating complex reports (MySQL/PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

PHP mysql_query function doesn't allow multiple queries, which limits maximal report complexity. What is the best practice, if I need really complex reports generated, which require multiple temp tables and multiple queries?

**UPDATE:** My question is more about how to use MySQL complex queries in PHP, if mysql_query only allows single query?

Comment: You can always use PDO, Which allows for multiple queries and multiple statements.

Comment: I think you could use transactions, temporary tables to get whatever report you need.

Comment: Maybe you could give an example of a query that you can't see how to do with mysql_query?

Comment: I don't see what `mysql_query` PHP function has to do with creating complex MySQL reports. If you need results of multiple queries, then you're using the wrong library which is also outdated. As @Truth said, use PDO.

Answer (score 1):

> PHP mysql_query function doesn't allow multiple queries, which limits maximal report complexity

Not in my experience it doesn't.

Temporary tables are available for the duration of the session - if you want to use temporary tables for composing your report (since the availability of sub-queries, they are not *required*) what's wrong with...

```
 mysql_query('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE workset ....
 mysql_query('INSERT INTO workset (...) SELECT ....
 mysql_query('UPDATE workset......
 ....
 mysql_query('SELECT * FROM workset....
```

Or using a stored procedure for creating a materialized view?

Answer (score 1):

well if you are looking for executing multiple queries, then why don't you use `mysqli_multi_query`
example taken out of PHP manual:

```
/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query  = "SELECT CURRENT_USER();";
$query .= "SELECT Name FROM City ORDER BY ID LIMIT 20, 5";

/* execute multi query */
if ($mysqli->multi_query($query)) {
    do {
        /* store first result set */
        if ($result = $mysqli->store_result()) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
                printf("%s\n", $row[0]);
            }
            $result->free();
        }
        /* print divider */
        if ($mysqli->more_results()) {
            printf("-----------------\n");
        }
    } while ($mysqli->next_result());
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

references:
[mysqli_multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)

Answer (score 0):

What did you mean about "maximal report complexity"? Now I use SSRS. But this is Microsoft solution. I googled that [Reportico Tools](http://www.reportico.org/swsite/site/home/index.php) may help you. As alternative, ZF (for example) contain huge functionality for interacting with databases. Possibly [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920889/open-source-php-reporting-tool) can help you.